# Assume X and Y are independent Poisson random variables with mean 1 and 3 respectively. Find Find P(X≤Y|X+Y =1)

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

I am having trouble finding P(X≤Y|X+Y =1). I know a conditional probability is going to be (P(X≤Y)AND P(X+Y =1)/ P(X+Y =1).

I am unsure how to find these separate variables in the multivariable sense. I realize they are independently distributed, so does that mean you can multiply individual poisson probabilities?

I don't know how to visualize the separate parts of this conditional probability, so I think that is where my main problem is. I understand these problems for conditional distributions, but the discrete problems I haven't visualized well.

Would the denominator be ((e^-1/1!))(3e^-3/1!)) ?

How would you then find the probability X

Comment: These are Poisson variables, no?  So $X+Y=1\implies (X,Y)=(0,1)$ or $(X,Y)=(1,0)$.

Comment: Try to visualize the domain $x \leq y$ given $x+y =1$

Comment: @lulu you are right, since poisson is discrete. So, I guess I am having trouble calculating the probability of this. Would P(X+Y =1) be the P(X=0,Y=1) +P(X=1,Y=0) from the probability function for a poisson model. Then you could do P(X=0) * P(Y=1) etc because the random variables are independent

Comment: Exactly.  $\quad$

Comment: @lulu okay, so would it make sense to say that since given the fact that (,)=(0,1) or (,)=(1,0) then the probability of x≤y is 1/2 ?

Comment: Certainly not, since the distributions are not the same.  You really do have to compute $P(0,1)$ and $P(1,0)$.  As a suggestion, don't compute them numerically...leave them in exponential form (the final answer is quite a simple rational number, though it is not $\frac 12$).

Comment: AHH 3/4. Thank you so much.

Comment: Perfect.  I'll post the calculation below to close off the question, but it seems clear that you've solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Since $X+Y=1$ we must have either $(X,Y)=(1,0)$ or $(X,Y)=(0,1)$

We compute:

$$P(1,0)=P(X=1)\times P(Y=0)=\frac {1^1\times e^{-1}}{1!}\times \frac {3^0\times e^{-3}}{0!}=e^{-4}$$

$$P(0,1)=P(X=0)\times P(Y=1)=\frac {1^0\times e^{-1}}{0!}\times \frac {3^1\times e^{-3}}{1!}=3e^{-4}$$

Thus $P(X+Y=1)= 4e^{-4}$

As the only case in which $X≤Y$ and $X+Y=1$ is $(X,Y)=(0,1)$ we get the final answer $$\frac {3e^{-4}}{4e^{-4}}=\boxed {\frac 34}$$